# Deploying Schnitzelpress on Heroku - Error

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

I am a CSS Designer who is now studying Programming through Ruby. Today, I was installing (or rather trying to install) Schnitzelpress, a Ruby blogging platform on Heroku -

http://schnitzelpress.org/manual/setup/

I followed the above guide to the T. All was well, until I arrived at this one -

git push heroku master

It gives me a `src refefspec master does not match` error and `error: failed to push some refs to...` error.

I read similar errors here in Stackoverflow, but in vain.

I am a beginner in programming, so can you, in layman's term help me out. I know the machine isn't wrong. It's me. I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Can you check to see if you have your remotes setup properly? If you do git remote -v, you should see a heroku remote origin. Also, git branch -ra shows all remote branches as well. You should see a remotes/heroku/master

Comment: Yes, I did a git remote -v (after you asked me to). I see the following - heroku git@heroku.com:dojoblog.git <fetch> heroku git@heroku.com:dojoblog.git <push>  What is the purpose of this? What do I do now?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'committing..'
git push
```

If there's  a problem try `git pull` and repeat